# round up with ceil and start from x value

Tags: math, calculation

I am using a plugin lately to do some calculations for my products in wordpress.
`ceil({uni_cpo_height} /10)*10`
Is the line i'm using currently to round up the customer input height by 10 centimeters.
But I need it to start from 150cm.
Is there a way i can combine this ceil calculation together with another operator which makes it start at 150?

Would appreciate the help, thankyou

Comment: I assume you tested your solution at least with values 1,2,3,4...17,18,19,20. Did the results satisfy you? What do you mean by "I need it to start from 150cm". Is there a difference of the desired result for values < 150 and > 150? What is it?

Comment: if the input in the field is 101 for example it gets calculated as 110 so it works as intended.
But what i want it to do is start from 150 even if the input in the field is 1 2 3 or 100.
I am no expert in arithmetic operators unfortunately, so i thought i could reach out for help at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So i've tried a couple things, and a friend reached out who found the solution
This piece of code did the trick:
`max(ceil({uni_cpo_height} /10)*10,150)`
now it rounds up by 10 cm and it starts at 150 cm, even if the input is below 150.

Comment: Only seeing this solution I understand what the goal of the question was. Could be me. Nice little puzzle though.